# Cant quite nail scaling the game on mobile. Its not showing all of the game but only part of the game

Tags: phaser-framework

```
    this.scale.scaleMode = Phaser.ScaleManager.SHOW_ALL;
    this.scale.pageAlignHorizontally = true;
    this.scale.pageAlignVertically = true;
    this.scale.refresh();
```

Its a tiny game code which I have uploaded on http://scaleissue.site44.com/ so pls use browser dev tools to have a look.

As you will notice when u go to dev tools and choose mobile emulation (iphone 4, 5, 6 - landscape orientation only), the screen only shows the top-left corner of the actual game with scroll bars when in fact it should have scaled the game such that all of the game was being shown on the screen since I used

```
    this.scale.scaleMode = Phaser.ScaleManager.SHOW_ALL;
```

(you might have to reload page to notice this issue when in dev tools). I tried the game on real mobile and still the same issue.

All relevant scaling code is under boot.js

Please help as I cant quite nail the issue having tried several scaling modes.

Comment: Your canvas has a hardcoded size, try using the window.innerHeight and window.innerWidth values

Comment: this is not going to work as the whole game needs to scale as a whole. If i use what u suggest, then its like scaling but all the game sprites and physics bounding boxes would be placed differently on different phones and basically u wont have the same level design on every phone.

Comment: The canvas has, to say so, two width values: canvas.width and canvas.style.width. The first one should be the second multiplied by the devicePixelRatio

Comment: Pablo, can u pls give a working example or code to explain a bit more? And i would even accept your answer for the effort. Just need more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to resize the canvas:

```
var width=window.innerWidth,
    height=window.innerHeight,
    dpr=window.devicePixelRatio || 1;


var game = window.game[NAMESPACE].game = new Phaser.Game(1024, 480, Phaser.AUTO, 'gameDiv');

var mainState = {

    preload : function () {
        game.scale.scaleMode = Phaser.ScaleManager.RESIZE ;
        //game.canvas.style.width=width+'px';
        game.canvas.style.height=height+'px';

    },
    create : function () {
        this.stage.backgroundColor = '#0000db';
    },
    update : function () {}
};
//initialising Phaser
game.state.add('main', mainState);
game.state.start('main');
```

The rationale behind this code: The canvas.width value (which is a number) sets the size of the game, while the canvas.style.width value (which is a string) sets the size of the canvas element. To avoid deformations you should maintain the same ratio (in your case, the ratio is 1024/480) in both values. If you set the ScaleManager as RESIZE then this ratio is maintained automatically, that's the reason why I'm only setting the height.

Comment: i understand what you are saying Pablo and did what you recommended but I still keep getting an error. Pls have a look at the code at testing2.site44.com and advise how to proceed. I just cannot make scaling work at all atm. So you are my only lifesaver.

Comment: Change this.canvas.style.height by this.game.canvas.style.height... there are others problems but that's the main one

Comment: What are the other problems please? Only asking cos it still isnt scaling like it should. Pls have a look at testing2.site44.com  Why isnt it scaling assets too? isnt there a way to scale the game as a whole just like Scalemanager.SHOW_ALL was supposed to do?